# Select, edit and then insert data into new database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, insert

What is the best way to `SELECT all from MYSQL DATABASE_1` almost every item edit (split, merge, validate email format, validate URL format, etc.) - by using php and then `INSERT INTO` new `DATABASE 2`.

The old table has almost 3 million rows.

If I do *foreach* for every row (which is not good idea :) ) it takes more than 1 hour for 2 thousand rows.

If I insert multiple rows in one query:

```
    INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (item1, item2, ...), (item3, item4, ...)
```

it is almost the same

Any ideas how to do it professionally and fast?

Comment: Because I have to edit almost each item. as I said, validate, replace something, split something. It is trash from not validated inputs.

Comment: mysql - as written in the first line of the post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it paging the query and using several php processes. For example, a process one retrieve and edit 100000 elements the insert into new DB.

To implement it you can create a php parent process that distributes the workload into child processes, something like this:

```
$total_rows = //Get from your mysql table
$offsets = []
$limit = 10000;

//Create offsets to process in bulk
for ($i=0 ; $i<$total_rows ; $i++) {
    $offsets[] = ($i * limit);
}

//Process rows
while ($processed_rows < $total_rows)

    $pids = [];

    //Create 10 childs processes
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        if ($pid) {
            $pids[] = $pid;
        } else {

            //Get next offset to process
            $offset = array_shift ($offsets);
            process_and_insert_row($offset, $limit); //this function gets, edits and inserts items
        }   
    }

    //Wait for childs to finish
    foreach ($pids as $pid) {
        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
        $processed_rows += $limit;
        unset($pids[$pid]);
    }
}
```

**Warning**: The code is not tested, but I think it demonstrates the idea behind the explanation...

Comment: This seems logical.  I'm gonna try it. Thank you.

Comment: Do only 1000 at a time -- else you may blow out RAM in PHP.  [_More discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) of chunking.